# Microsoft Sentinel - How to remove automation playbook templates

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

At the moment I'm trying out functionality inside Microsoft Sentinel. I have deployed the VirusTotal module from the content hub. This included 8 Playbooks for me to use. I have since then seen that I need a paid API key, so I wanted to stop using it and clean everything up.

I deleted the module from the content hub and was aware that it would not delete everything. So I went to the resource group, looked at the relevant deployment and promptly deleted every resource it deployed and then the deployment itself. As far as my knowledge goes there is nothing left, but the playbook templates still remain inside Sentinel's Automation tab.

What am I missing? It's probably something obvious, I just want it cleaned up. Thanks in advance.

This is the stuff that's still in Sentinel:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are four Virus Total Playbook templates that come "in-the-box" when you stand up Microsoft Sentinel.

You're probably just seeing the templates we provide.

Comment: I've added the relevant picture to the OP post, can you look there?

Comment: dbl checked, those comes by default.